# Explaining anonymous function

Tags: javascript

Can anybody explain below code? All I know is it is anonymous function but what is `(0)` doing?

```
var output = (function(x) {
 delete x;
 return x;
})(0);
console.log(output);
```

Why output of above code comes zero. Can anybody explain?

Comment: It is a [Immediately-Invoked Function Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript) to which `0` is passed as first argument.

Comment: You put 0 in, it splits 0 out. That's about it (ignoring the useless `delete`).

Comment: is a variable not a property and so it can't be deleted. a property would be `delete x.y` if `x = { y: 5};`

Comment: [MDN: delete examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete#Examples), delete on a local variable or parameter will do nothing and (and as of that returns `false` for that `delete`). So you can just remove the `delete x;` form the given code without changing anything about its logic.

Answer (score 0):

That's because what you're doing is creating a function and then calling it immediately where x = 0. Your function is returning x, and thus 0.

As for what anonymous functions are, they are basically a function that gets stored in a variable. You call it from the variable instead of by name. So, for example:

```
var output = function (x) { return x;};
```

Can be called like this:

```
output(0);
```

As opposed to the normal way like this:

```
function myOutput(x) {
    return x;
}

myOutput(0);
```